# Oracle SQL new Column with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

i have some SQL to do but i can't find how to do that.
I have this query:

```
SELECT ENAME AS Name, SAL AS Salary FROM EMP WHERE (SELECT max(SAL) FROM EMP) = SAL OR (SELECT min(SAL) FROM EMP) = SAL;
```

Now I want to have another column which displays if it is Maximum or Minimum SAL.

So that I get something like that:

```
MaxOrMin  Name    Salary 
Max       Frank   50,000
Max       Peter   50,000
Min       Patric  20,000
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using analytic functions:

```
select ename as name, sal as salary,
       (case when sal = max(sal) over () then 'max'
             when sal = min(sal) over () then 'min'
        end) as MaxOrMin
from emp;
```